# Reopen a question from the Stack Exchange iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, vote-to-reopen

A couple minutes ago I had a flag on a question. The question is now fine, but I can not reopen it, because I'm connected from the iOS app.

I can see only the reason that my question was flagged and a link how to write a question. Is there any reopen button?